# upstart to run python under virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, upstart

Python script location:

`~/src/myproject/python/bin/myproject.py`

I went to directory:

`~/src/myproject/python`

and ran:

`workon myproject-dev`

Then I run the following commands. Everything is fine.

```
(myproject-dev)myadmin@myhost:~/src/myproject/python$ which python
/home/myadmin/.virtualenvs/myproject-dev/bin/python
(myproject-dev)myadmin@myhost:~/src/myproject/python$ python ~/src/myproject/python/bin/myproject.py -c ~/src/temp/myproject.conf
```

I planed to use upstart script to do the above job, but failed. I searched the problems, such as https://gist.github.com/swinton/1978897. But still no idea. Below is the upstart script. Any suggestion is welcome.

```
env PYTHON_HOME=/home/myadmin/.virtualenvs/myproject-dev

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

script
    cd ~/src/myproject/python
    workon myproject-dev#activate the virtualenv
    add2virtualenv /home/myadmin/src/myproject/python#Add myproject source to path
    exec $PYTHON_HOME/bin/python ~/src/myproject/python/bin/myproject.py -c ~/src/temp/myproject.conf
end script
```

**UPDATE**

After running "sudo service test-env start", the output is

```
start/running, process 12361
```

Then running "sudo service test-env status", the output is

```
test-env stop/waiting
```

The service failed to start...

Comment: Check the log files (on ubuntu /var/log/upstart/test-env.log)